# Adding US style(XXX-XXX-XXXX) phone number field to the registration form in Drupal7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How to add US style(XXX-XXX-XXXX) phone number field to the registration form in Drupal7? Which CCK field should be chosen for this field type(XXX-XXX-XXXX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Phone contrib module](http://drupal.org/project/phone).

> Validation of phone numbers for : France, Belgium, Great Britain,
>   Switzerland, Italy, Greece, Netherlands, Israel, Russia, Ukraine,
>   Australia, Spain, Czech, Hungary, Poland (mobile only), Costa Rica,
>   Panama, Brazil, Chili, New Zealand, China, Hong-Kong, Macau,
>   Philippine, Singapore, Swiss, Jordanian, Egyptian, South Africa,
>   Pakistan, US and Canada

Comment: I have tried this module previously only. But its not giving the same view as expected in US style phone number.